# Header redirect, sessions lost, but only after about 5 minutes

Tags: php, redirect, header, session

```
function redirect($url){
    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}
```

I have the function called when certain input buttons are clicked.

The session is set on every page, and it IS passed if the the button is clicked within 5 minutes. But the session is lost after about 5 minutes if the button is clicked.

If I refresh the page (not redirect) the session is not lost, so I'm pretty sure it's not a timeout issue. What could be causing this?

Comment: Note that 303 is supposed to be used for redirects in response on POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to add this line to my custom php.ini file. For some reason the session needs an explicitly direct session file to save in a local directory.

`session.save_path = /path/to/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this part of your php.ini file and restart apache:

```
; TTL for user-defined php.ini files (time-to-live) in seconds. Default is 300 seconds (5 minutes)
;user_ini.cache_ttl = 300
```

Comment: Uncommenting the user_ini.cache_ttl and increasing the number would extend the time-to-live on the user's cache.  It's set at 5 minutes by default.  It's most likely where your problems are coming from.

(You have to restart apache in order for changes to php.ini to take effect)

Comment: Is it LAMP or WAMP?  On WAMP some metapackages make funny extra php.ini files that don't actually change the configuration.  

In LAMP there is a php.ini file for both the php-cli and server installations.

...and...just to be sure; you got rid of the ";" at the front of the line?  I apologize for the silly question.  Just making sure.

Comment: Ok...  When you redirect does it go to the same domain?  Or a subdomain?  Also; do you have cookies enabled?